# android.security.keystore.KeyNotYetValidException: Key not yet valid on Android 11

Tags: android, android-keystore

Recently upgraded my Pixel 2 to Android 11 and now am starting to see this exception when trying to decrypt a string that was encrypted with the same keystore and keypair:
android.security.keystore.KeyNotYetValidException: Key not yet valid

The same code was working correctly on the previous version of Android (Android 8) that was on the phone. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app to clear out data but even a string encrypted a minute ago fails decryption with the key not valid exception. The date and time on the phone are correct.

```
Error decrypting string: 
    android.security.keystore.KeyNotYetValidException: Key not yet valid
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1318)
        at android.security.KeyStore.getInvalidKeyException(KeyStore.java:1388)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getInvalidKeyExceptionForInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:54)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.getExceptionForCipherInit(KeyStoreCryptoOperationUtils.java:89)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:265)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineInit(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:148)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2980)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2891)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2796)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:773)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1288)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1223)
```

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution to this? I seem to be facing the exact same issue on a Pixel2 with Android 11.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Have created a Google bug for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177046277. Please star this to raise it's priority!

Comment: Thanks! It is very weird. My teammates have tried quite a lot already and nothing seems to work. We are currently adding more tracking to figure out if there are other phone/OS combinations where it happens. For now we have the Pixel 2 and Oppo Reno 6

Comment: Thanks for this info! Please post any info you find including devices that exhibit this error to the above Android issue as that is assigned to someone in the Google dev team so hopefully someone is working on it. I don't have much hope for the Pixel 2 as it is an older device but if newer devices are having this problem, Google may be more inclined to fix it.

Comment: Will do! For starters, look at the stars of the google issue you created ;).

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! Hope the folks at Google are noticing! :)

Comment: It happens to me on OnePlus 6. Did you find any solution for this issue?